# How do I hide field on edit/new record page and still display them in the view page?

Tags: case, custom-field, permissions, page-layout

We have quite a few custom fields, a good portion of the fields are populated by automated processes and are read-only to the agents. When an agent goes to create a new case, they see tons of fields that they can't touch.

Is it possible to hide these custom fields on the Create and Edit page, but not the display view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of the box you can't specify different fields for the view/edit/new page layouts. You can only specify which fields are editable/required/read-only. Some options to consider.

#### Record Type Switching

Since the displayed page layout is based on the profile / record type you can in effect create two layouts one for a new record which is displayed when creating a new object, and another layout for viewing and editing an existing record. When a new record is saved use workflow or process builder to change the record type.

#### Page Overrides

If custom development is an option you can override the new / edit / view pages for a case independently allowing you to display different fields in each scenario. This requires creating a visualforce page and/or lightning component.

#### Quick Actions

With quick actions you can create a specific form for creating cases. It won't override the 'New' button globally, but you can hide that where possible and replace it with your quick action. Once the record is created the fields displayed when viewing or editing would be driven by the page layout.

Answer (score 1):

By George I think I have solved this one. I documented it here, https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000JfmWPSAZ make sure to read both my comments. It includes a step by step equivalent to @ChatanyaWalukar 's IsNew solution since, like others, I wasn't able to find IsNew (maybe they created IsNew as a formula field? In any case I think my solution achieves the same thing without the need to create such a formula field.)

Comment: Salesforce has a pretty bad track record when it comes to breaking links. Please reproduce the solution and explanation here so that this answer can still be useful after Salesforce decides to break links (or rebrand) again.

Comment: In Lightning App Builder:
    Click "Set Field Visibility" or "Set Component Visibility"
    Click "add Filter"
    Click "Advanced"
    Click "Select" (next to Field)

In the "Select field" interface:
    Click drop down arrow and select "Record." A new "Type to filter list" box should appear
    Click drop down arrow and select "Created By." A new "Type to filter list" box should appear 
     Click drop down arrow and select "Username."
    Click "Done" 

In filter interface:
    Set Operator to "Not Equal"
    Type '' (two apostrophes, not one quote symbol.)
    Click "Done"

Comment: Great solution (as mentioned in the comment directly above), work's like a charm! Many thanks @ThaddeusFerber

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to create a simple Visualforce page with the fields you want them to see when creating a new case and overwrite the "New" page on the Case's Buttons, Links, and Actions.

This way you can control the number of fields they can see on the creation on a new Case.

From Setup:

1. Build
2. Case
3. Buttons, Links and Actions
4. Click Edit on label "New"
5. Select the visualforce page that you want to use.

That should do it.

Let me know if I can help you with the visualforce page, but it would be better if you try your self.

Comment: I'd avoid code if you can help it. Have you tried creating a new recordtype and page layout? Then when the record is saved change the record type? Then you can control the fields that are on the "create record". The edit page will then remove all the read only fields anyway as they can't be edited.

Comment: Instead of changing the recordtype on save, it better to create and set a dedicated pagelayout which contain necessary fields for all the agent profiles.

Comment: There are also 'quick actions'

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are populated by automated system, I guess that those fields does not need to be changed. You can create custom formula field which will be linked to the original fields. By doing this, you will have fields shown in the view layout, but not be able to be changed (old fields will be removed from the layout).

Answer (score 0):

[image]Use Lightning record page for this purpose.
And click on the field that you want to hide in new/edit form. and add filter ISNEW equals false .

So while creating new record it will not show that filed. But on detail page you can see that filed with its auto-populated value.

Comment: How do you reference ISNEW() as an operator here?

Comment: Hmmm, @ChatanyaWalukar - how did you access that ISNEW field here?

Comment: You can find it in filters

Comment: Looks like isNew your custom field *facepalm*